# I have a question about Temperature and materials. Can anyone help please?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

Let's say you have a slab of material of thickness (x) and one side is exposed to a temperature. I need an equation that represents what the temperature will be on the other side of the slab. I assume you need to take into account the material properties, such as optical thickness or opacity etc.

Comment: Assuming no other sources of heat, the other side will eventually reach the same temperature.  I doubt this is what you had in mind, though - is there a physical situation you were thinking of?

Comment: You're looking for the heat equation.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. As per comment by J Murray. Also, what has the optical thickness and opacity got to do with this problem?

Comment: So I guess I was thinking if you had a sealed box made of metal and inside was air. If you heated the box from the outside, how hot would it be on the inside? It would depend on the thickness of the metal but surely it also depends on the type of metal?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the solution of the [1-D heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) $$\alpha\frac{\partial^2 T(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial T(x,t)}{\partial t}$$

where $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity of the material and $T(x,t)$ is the temperature in the slab at distance $x$ and time $t$, subject to the boundary conditions $T(x=0,t)=T_\mathrm{left}(t)$, $T(x,t=0)=T_0$, and whatever the boundary condition on the right side. The only material property involved is the thermal diffusivity. Depending on the boundary condition on the right side (e.g., convection, conduction, radiation, etc.) and whether $T_\mathrm{left}(t)$ is nonconstant there may be no closed-form solution for the temperature on the right side of the slab; thus, you may need to solve the equation numerically.

Books on partial differential equations for scientists and engineers generally discuss how to determine analytical and numerical solutions for such problems.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Ok so that’s a lot more complicated than I expected. But thank you for the explanation.